# Order of vertices when UV "Reset" is used - given a face

Tags: python

I'm working on a custom exporter and I need to know how the vertices are sorted when you use the "Reset" method to unwrap the vertices.

When unwrappings quads, one vertex gets the 0,0, another one the 1,0 and so on, but I cannot find the order in which the default UVs are assigned to these vertices.

They don't seem to be sorted by the vertex index, nor the loop_index when iterating the face.

Does anyone know how the vertices inside a face get assigned the default UVs when using "Reset"?